# Why do my lines rotate in a peculiar fashion?

Tags: c, bgi

I am trying to design a fan and make the lines rotate using C language.

*This is my code:*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<math.h>

void main(){
    int gd=DETECT,gm=0,xr,yr,xr1,yr1,xr2,yr2,x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2;
    int x3,y3,i;
    float rad;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI");
    x=getmaxx()/2;
    y=getmaxy()/2;
    printf("x1 and y1:");
    scanf("%d %d",&x1,&y1);
    printf("x2 and y2:");
    scanf("%d %d",&x2,&y2);
    printf("x3 and y3:");
    scanf("%d %d",&x3,&y3);
    printf("\n\n");
    setcolor(RED);
    line(x,y,x1,y1);
    line(x,y,x2,y1);
    line(x,y,x3,y3);
    rad=toRadians(1);

    for(i=0;i<60;i++){

        xr=x+((x1-x)*cos(0.017)-(y1-y)*sin(0.017));
        yr=y+((x1-x)*sin(0.017)+(y1-y)*cos(0.017));
        xr1=x+((x2-x)*cos(0.017)-(y2-y)*sin(0.017));
        yr1=y+((x2-x)*sin(0.017)+(y2-y)*cos(0.017));
        xr2=x+((x3-x)*cos(0.017)-(y3-y)*sin(0.017));
        yr2=y+((x3-x)*sin(0.017)+(y3-y)*cos(0.017));
        setcolor(RED);
        line(x,y,xr,yr);
        line(x,y,xr1,yr1);
        line(x,y,xr2,yr2);
        x1=xr;
        y1=yr;
        x2=xr1;
        y2=yr1;
        x3=xr2;
        y3=yr2;
        delay(500);
        cleardevice();

    }

    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

The problem is that the lines don't rotate in a synchronized way. It's like one line is rotating, then after some time the second line starts rotating and so on. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Rather than overwriting your initial `x1`,`x2` and `x3` at the end of your loop, it would make more sense to increase the angle that you're passing to `sin` and `cos`.

Comment: But I want all the three lines to rotate by the same angle.

Comment: Ok it is working

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your compiler, you might see a warning like this:

> '=': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

This is pretty much telling you what's going on. You declared your coordinates as `int` but the trigonometric functions produce `double`. Very small ones to be precise. `int` is just not able to capture these small changes and will throw away any digit after the decimal point as soon as you do the assignment to `xr` etc.

To solve this, simply declare your variables as `double`. You can then convert these to `int` before passing them to `line()`. But you keep your calculations in `double` precision:

```
line((int)round(x), (int)round(y), (int)round(xr), (int)round(yr));
...
```

Another way that circumvents this problem is to increase the angle and calculate the rotated directions from the original values as 3Dave suggested in the comments.

The main take-away message here is: Do not ignore warnings that your compiler gives you.

Comment: First of all variables `xr`, `xr1`, etc are already in `int`, so I don't think typecasting is required, secondly the linker shows some kind of an error in `round()` (I don't know why) but third of all 3Dave's method is working, I've increased the angle from 1 degree to 5 degrees and now it rotates perfectly.

Comment: If you follow my advice ("declare your variables as `double`), they won't be `int` anymore. What Dave meant was not to increase the angle to 5 degrees but to hold an `angle` variable an increase that in each iteration.